# T-SQL - Work backward through values till I get something above Zero

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have Billing Rate History table.  We are required to report billing rate changes to clients, so I compare this period's (month) billing rate to that of last period.  If there is a delta, I report that.  At the close of the routine, I record current rates for comparison next month.  It works fine, but there is a challenge...

If employee Tom Thumb works for the client in question this month, but did not work last month, there is nothing against which to compare.  Or, if Tom worked Overtime this month, but only straight time last month, I have no overtime rate against which to compare.

I'm trying to find a way to walk backward by Period till I find a valid > 0 rate for comparison.

So, let's say we are billing Period 201403.
Tom has a straight time bill rate of 54.04 for Period 201403.
He has an overtime rate of 81.06 for that same Period.

Now, I look at Period 201402 for his straight time and overtime rate.  If there is no delta, I move on to the next employee.

But what if Tom has no ST or OT rate in Period 201402?  I need to walk backward to 201401, 201312, etc. till I find the rate he had the last time he worked for this client.

I've read that it is not a good practice to use loops on a DB.  What's the best practice for accomplishing what I need to accomplish?

Comment: You should set up a SQL Fiddle with some sample data.

Comment: Also, please stipulate the version of SQL Server you are using, as this may influence the feasible results people submit for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a cte, a self-join, and a ranking function. Something like:

```
with cte as (
   select *, row_number() over (partition by employeeid order by periodid) as [rn]
)
select employeeid, curr.billrate, [last].billrate
from cte as [curr]
left join cte as [last]
  on curr.employeeid = last.employeeid
  and curr.rn = last.rn + 1
```

You'll have to jigger this to fit your actual table structure, but this should get you pretty close. Feel free to add a where clause (i.e. `where curr.billrate <> [last].billrate`)